# How to play video only in webview not in full screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I am new in swift and I am facing problem in playing video in WKWebView. 
My code is like this

```
@IBOutlet var youtubeWebView: WKWebView!

    func setContentView(homeVideoListModel:HomeVideoListModel?){
        //youtubeWebView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

               guard var videoUrl = homeVideoListModel?.videoUrl else {
        return
    }

    videoUrl = videoUrl + "?playsinline=1"
    print(videoUrl)

    let youtubeUrl = URL(string: videoUrl)!
    let youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: youtubeUrl ?? URL(string: "")!)

    youtubeWebView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    youtubeWebView.load(youtubeRequest)
```

I only want to play video in WKWebView not in full screen

Comment: show your `youtubeUrl`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J04ZicM1vCI

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Still the problem is same nothing happen with this code